# Passing int from one Function to another

Tags: iphone, variables

I really have no idea how this is done, it should be simple but i just cant get it

i have an IBAction and void and want to do this:

```
   -(IBAction)pass{
int VariableX = 10;
[self getVar]; ---> send var to -(void)getVar

}


-(void)getVar{

get the VariableX

if(VariableX=10){
do something
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declare getVar function to get one (integer) parameter:

```
// header
-(void)getVar:(int)varX;

// implementation
-(void)getVar:(int)varX{
   if (varX == 10)
      // do something
}
```

Then call it the following way:

```
-(IBAction)pass{
   int VariableX = 10;
   [self getVar:VariableX];
}
```

Generally the syntax of method declaration in objective-c is:

```
- (ReturnType) functionName:(1st parameter type)1stParameterName 
               2ndParameter:(2nd parameter type)2ndParameterName
               etc
```

Comment: This is most essential and basic knowledge however, I strongly suggest looking into some beginners Objective C tutorials...

Comment: I appreciate your advice Toastor but I was asking for some guidance because sometimes people like Vladimir are more experienced and can explain things for easier comprehension. Vladimir thanks a lot